# Fill a ListView based on a List<Items>

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, fragment

I'm new to StackOverflow and this is my first question.
I've been looking everywhere for help but haven't find anything that works for me.

I'm working on Android Studio 0.8.14 and I want to populate a ListView based on a List of Items that I get from SQLite and everyone says I should use the ArrayAdapter but that's not working for me, can someone help me out??

This is how I build the List of Items:

```js
//getting all items
public List < Item > getAllItems() {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  List < Item > items = new ArrayList < Item > ();
  String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ITEM;
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

  // looping through all rows and adding to list
  if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
      Item it = new Item();
      it.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
      it.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
      it.setDescription(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DESCRIPTION)));
      it.setPrice(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE)));
      it.setAdd_info(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADD_INFO)));
      it.category_id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ITEM_CATEGORY));
      it.vegetarian = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VEGETARIAN));
      it.sustainable = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SUSTAINABLE));
      it.vegan = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_VEGAN));
      it.frozen = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FROZEN));
      it.gluten_free = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_GLUTEN_FREE));
      it.gm_free = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_GM_FREE));

      // adding to item list
      items.add(it);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
  }
  return items;
}
```

On my MainActivity.java I have this:

```js
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  private DatabaseHelper db;
  List < String > categoryNames;
  int categoryCount = 0;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_categories);
    
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    categoryNames = db.getAllCategoryNames();
    categoryCount = catNames.size();

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) { super(fm); }

    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

      if (index >= 0 && index < categoryCount)
        return new ListTheItems();
      else
        return null;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      String title = "no title";

      if (position >= 0 && position < categoryCount) {
        title = categoryNames.get(position);
      }

      return title;
    }

    public int getCount() {
      return categoryCount;
    }
  }


}
```

And this is ListTheItems.java where I try to show the data from the List of Items in the ListView:

```js
public class ListTheItems extends Fragment {

  private List < Item > allItems = new ArrayList < Item > ();
  private DatabaseHelper db;
  private ListView listView;

  public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemList);
    allItems = db.getAllItems();

    ArrayAdapter < String > arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
      allItems);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
  }
}
```

I'm using Fragments, but inside the ListTheItems.java i get errors on the methods 'setContentView' , 'findViewById' and cannot resolve the 'ArrayAdapter' constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you load your view hierarchy into a fragment than it how you load it into an Activity. Try this instead:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout. list, container, false);
    // You have to call findViewById on rootView, since the fragment doesn't know
    // what your views are until you return rootView from this function
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemList);

    allItems = db.getAllItems();
    Activity activity = (Activity) container.getContext();
    ArrayAdapter < Item > arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < Item > (activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
      allItems);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I missed the type difference. The reason you are getting the constructor error is that the template-type of your List parameter needs to match the template-type of your ArrayAdapter. I've fixed the code above, changing the type of arrayAdapter to ArrayAdapter < Item > to match the type of allItems, which is a List < Item >.

Comment: I have already tried something like that.
Here: (activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allItems);
I get an error saying: " Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(android.app.Activity,int,java.util.List<com.example...Item>)'"

I've been stuck here for so long dunno what to do!

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution for my problem was create my own Adapter and based on @Bruce's help change MainActivity.java like this:

```js
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
  if (index >= 0 && index < categoryCount) {
    ListItemsFragment lif = new ListItemsFragment();
    lif.allItems = db.getAllItemsByCategory(index + 1);
    return lif;
  } else
    return null;
}
```

and change the ListTheItems.java like this:

```js
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
  listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
  MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this.getActivity(), allItems);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  return rootView;
}
```